# Add E-mail address into Body as a link

Tags: vba, outlook, html-email

I have written a macro that creates an email.
There should be text in the email.

I want to store an e-mail address for queries. Is it possible to store this e-mail as a link?

```vb
Dim MyMessage As Object
Dim OutlookApplication As Object

Set OutlookApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyMessage = OutlookApplication.createitem(0)
With MyMessage
    .to = ....
    .Subject = "Test"
    .htmlbody = "Click me <a href=mailto:me@test.com>Click</a>"
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221391/formatting-an-excel-vba-email-with-variables/45221890#45221890

Comment: It worked for me using Outlook 2019. I didn't set the BodyFormat property, just put your string in the HTMLBody propery. When you say it doesn't work, you mean the HTML shows up as is in the body rather than being rendered?

Comment: What exactly did not work? Are you saying the newly created message body has no mailto link?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) property which returns or sets an `OlBodyFormat` constant indicating the format of the body text before setting up the HTML content. Note, the `HTMLBody` property returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Try to use a well-formed HTML document, not just an anchor tag.

The body text format determines the standard used to display the text of the message. Microsoft Outlook provides three body text format options: Plain Text, Rich Text (RTF), and HTML. And all text formatting will be lost when the `BodyFormat` property is switched from RTF to HTML and vice-versa.